# How to fork a python script in different terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I want to fork a new process in a script, but how to interactive with the subprocess in a new terminal?
For example:

```
#python
a='a'
b='b'
if os.fork():
    print a
    a = input('a?')
    print 'a:',a
else:
    print b
    b = input('b?')
    print 'b:',b
```

The script should print a/b and ask for a new value. But these two process share a same terminal, and that makes it confused.

How can I open a new terminal and let the subprocess run in the new terminal?

---

I've thought about to use `subprocess.Popen('gnome-terminal',shell=True)` and communicate with the new terminal. But `gnome-terminal` will open bash on default, how can i open a terminal only for input and output?

Comment: It is not clear to me, why different processes are needed. Maybe a simple dialog/graphical user interface is more straightforward. For example, see [Graphical user interfaces with Tk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) and [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I'm writing a little Frame, can run different tasks at the same time. The tasks may need interactive at the same time. And the main script could configure all the tasks and run them, so i want them to run in different terminal. But i do not think GUI is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I finally implement it in a(maybe ugly) way.

Inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256480/how-do-i-run-a-command-in-a-new-terminal-window-in-the-same-process-as-the-origi
I'v solve most of the problem:

```
#python
import sys,os,subprocess
a='a'
b='b'
if os.fork():
    print a
    a = raw_input('a?')
    print 'a:',a
else:
    p = subprocess.Popen("xterm -e 'tty >&3; exec sleep 99999999' 3>&1",
                     shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,   stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    tty_path = p.stdout.readline().strip()
    tty = open(tty_path,'r+')
    sys.stdout=tty
    sys.stderr=tty
    sys.stdin=tty
    print b
    b = raw_input('b?')
    print 'b:',b
```

The only problem is that the prompt: 'b?' will still show in the former terminal. So the new question is: where does prompt belongs?

---

Despite that, another way to solve this prompt problem:

```
_r_i = raw_input
def raw_input(prompt):
    print prompt,
    return _r_i('')
```

---

I'm a little strange and, mad... I know...

Answer (score 0):

Its probably bad practice to open a new terminal like that from a command line application, but `gnome-terminal` has an `-e` flag. E.g. `gnome-terminal -e python` will open a python interpreter.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I'm doing. But the problem is that the environment of python interpreter will lost. So I try to use fork() to keep the interpreter status. But I cant do both at the same time. Thank you all the same.